# Is it Okay to launch web URLs in UIWebView in iosApp?

Tags: ios5, uiwebview

I am not sure if this is grounds of app rejection or not:

In my app I receive JSON data from webserver and it has html content like
       "[html] a href www.mycompany/view/regulations.html"... click for regulations...[/html]"

Is it okay to show the contents of the url above when clicking on "Click for regulations" link, or will this be rejected because I am under the impression that all html has to be carried locally?

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be a problem. We have an app were our TOS is loaded from an (online) URL. What they usually don't like if your *code* loads from an external source.